# How to add a error or sucess message on the same page, when the user submits a message in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I want to know how to add a error or sucess message on the same page, when the user submits a message, with all fields correct.

*PS:I am working on localhost and know very little of PHP, so please explain like I'm 5. Thanks*

```
 <?php

    $errorMSG = "";

    // NAME
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $errorMSG = "Por favor preencha o seu nome ";
    } else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    // EMAIL
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $errorMSG .= "Por favor preencha com o seu email ";
    } else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    // MSG SUBJECT
    if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
        $errorMSG .= "Por favor escreva um assunto da mensagem";
    } else {
        $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
    }


    // MESSAGE
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $errorMSG .= "Por favor escreva uma mensagem ";
    } else {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
    }

    //email here
    $EmailTo = "email@hotmail.com";
    $Subject = "New Message Received";

    //email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Nome: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Assunto: ";
    $Body .= $msg_subject;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Mensagem: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "De:".$email);

    //success message
    if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
       echo "sucesso";
    }else{
        if($errorMSG == ""){
            echo "Algo correu mal :(";
        } else {
            echo $errorMSG;
        }
    }

    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- css -->
    <link href="css/contactform.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>


                            <!-- Start Contact Form -->
    <form role="form" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required data-error="Por favor escreva o seu nome">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="email" class="email form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required data-error="Por favor escreva o seu email">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto" required data-error="Por favor escreva o assunto da mensagem">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <textarea id="message" rows="7" placeholder="Mensagem" class="form-control" required data-error="Escreva a sua mensagem"></textarea>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>  
      </div>

      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-effect"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Enviar</button>
      <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div> 
      <div class="clearfix"></div>   

    </form>
```

Also, I configured sendmail's "sendmail.ini" and "php.ini" file so as to test the receiving of emails on my local server, but keep getting this error: `Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in`

What's `custom "From:"?`

Comment: This is not possible by means of php, since php is running server side, whilst you need client side logic to modify an already loaded page. The usual approach is to transmit the form using an AJAX request to the server. The response contains your message which can be injected into the already shown page by means of javascript. Sounds scary but is actually much easier that most people expect.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i explain further, i have to point out that you didn't define or specify action attribute in your form. Your php code in it written form can't work, firstly you have to add action and method attribute to form element like this

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"   method="post">
  //input element here
</form>
```

The action attribute point to location of script(PHP file in your case) that will process the form data submitted by the user, but in your case, you want the php itself to process the form data, the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] contain the current php file location. For security reason, the php super global "$_SERVER" is wrap inside "htmlspecialchars" function, which escape the spacial characters. Secondly, because your submitting the form to the same php script, you have to check whether the form has been submitted, not when user visit the php page using $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]. If the REQUEST_METHOD is POST, then the form has been submitted, example:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  //put your validation code here
}
```

To make it clearer, this is how your php code suppose look like:

```
<?php
  //global variables here
  $errorMSG = "";
  $name = "";
  $email = "";
  $msg_subject = "";
  $message = "";
  $EmailTo = "";
  $Subject = "";
  $Body = "";

  //check if user submitted a form
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // NAME
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
      $errorMSG = "Por favor preencha o seu nome ";
    }
    else {
      $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    // EMAIL
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
      $errorMSG .= "Por favor preencha com o seu email ";
    } 
    else {
      $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    // MSG SUBJECT
    if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
      $errorMSG .= "Por favor escreva um assunto da mensagem";
    }
    else {
      $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
    }

    // MESSAGE
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
      $errorMSG .= "Por favor escreva uma mensagem ";
    } 
    else {
      $message = $_POST["message"];
    }

    //email here
    $EmailTo = "email@hotmail.com";
    $Subject = "New Message Received";

    //email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Nome: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Assunto: ";
    $Body .= $msg_subject;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Mensagem: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "De:".$email);

    //success message
    if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
      echo "sucesso";
    }
    else{
      if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Algo correu mal :(";
      }
      else {
        echo $errorMSG;
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

I notice that all your input element has no name attribute, which is the name your php script use to access the form data submitted by the user, this is right way to do it:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
```

Another thing you have to take note of, php code execute before the html and JavaScript had a chance.

Don't use this for production php code, for more information on how to correctly do this, visit this website https//www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "sucesso";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Algo correu mal :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}
}
?>` And also added the action to the button, as you suggested.What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I have re-edited the answer to reflect your question. I hope it helps?

Comment: There is error in my code sample above, action and method attribute is defined inside form element not inside input element. I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add action to your form this way, method and properly submit it.. try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>  

 <?php
 // define variables and set to empty values
  $nameErr = $emailErr =  "";
 $name = $email =  "";

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
  $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
   $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
   }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
     }
    }


     }

     function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
   }
   ?>


    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo      htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
     <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>

    <?php
    echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
     echo $name;
     echo "<br>";
     echo $email;
     echo "<br>";

   ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: take your html part up and php part down.. I think this may work for you...

Comment: Do you mean moving the HTML above the PHP script? I thought it needed to come first so the error or success message would be read before the loading the page..

Comment: I tried your suggestions and it's not really working. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.